# PyWavelets module installation issues and importing pywt error

Tags: python, import, pywt

May I know what should I do to fix the error of importing pywt?

My Python version is 3.11.1.
I have installed PyWavelets to my PyCharm using command prompt: pip install PyWavelets.
It shows that the "Requirement already satisfied: PyWavelets in c: and also numpy>=1.17.3 in c"
So, I think the version is already satisfied.

The problem is when I use "Import pywt" to run for wavelet transform function, it has got a red balloon and I clicked to install the package which leads to "Installing packages: error occurred. Details…".
Then I clicked to view the "Details" and it shows:

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pywt (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pywt

[notice] A new release of pip available: 22.3.1 -> 23.0.1
[notice] To update, run: python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip

So, I updated the pip version yet does not resolve my issue.
I am very clueless now on which part did I do it wrong.

Another thing that I noticed is that when I checked the Python Interpreter, the PyWavelets package was not found. I wonder why.

1. I have double checked the version of Python, Numpy, pip and all have fulfilled the requirement.
2. I even specified the latest version of PyWavelets which is 1.4.1.But still the importing of pywt is failed.
3. I have made sure that I do not have 2 versions of Python.
4. I checked at the Settings there to add "Python Interpreter", but did not see the PyWavelets package. I tried to search using the keywords "pywt". However, it only shows:

- PyWt: No information available. (I supposed this is the one that I need but when I clicked it shows "Error occurred when installing package)
- pywtdlib
- pywtf
- pywttr
- pywttr-models

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the error stated, after multiple attempt on troubleshooting it, I have finally able to install PyWavelets and import it to my coding.

The solution is as follows:

1. Go to **File** and **Settings**.
2. Select **Python Interpreter** and click the **+ sign**.
3. Please search the package by typing **PyWavelets** instead of **pywt**
   (as I searched with **pywt** it will show **PyWt** but not the one that I
   want)
4. Please click the **Install Package** at the left bottom of the
   window and there you are.
5. To use it in your coding, please type
   `Import pywt` , then you can now run wavelet transform without any
   issue.

I am using Windows 11.

My Python version is Python 3.11.1.

The PyWavelets package version is 1.4.1.

The numpy package version is 1.24.2.

So hopefully it helps to anyone of you who are also experiencing the same issue as me.